# Term for candidates for inflection points

Tags: calculus, terminology, derivative

The critical points of a function $f(x)$ are candidates for local extrema, i.e., if a function changes from increasing to decreasing, or vice versa, it must happen at a critical point.

Is there an analogous term for candidates for inflection points? The mathematical definition is analogous - if a function changes from positive concavity to negative concavity at a point, or vice versa, it must happen at a point $a$ in the domain of $f$ where $f''(a)=0$ or where $f''(a)$ does not exist - but what do we call such a point (if we call it anything at all)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a question specific to teaching or something that should be asked over on Mathematics StackExchange. I suppose it could work on either site.

Comment: Personally, I'm unaware of a specific term. I just use "candidate for inflection point" and notice that students often assume that $f''(a)=0$ guarantees an inflection point, despite the example of $f(x)=x^4$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I also call these "potential" or "candidate" points of inflection. But also point out what you have, that these candidate inflection points are critical points of $f'$

Comment: @Carser: Yes, I thought of calling these points "critical points of $f'$," but this could cause some confusion. I was hoping for an entirely different term. Thanks though!

Comment: They aren't quite "critical"... maybe they are only "important"? :P

Comment: @XanderHenderson, a candidate to inflection point ($f''(x) = 0$) isn't necessarily a critical point ($f'(x) = 0$).

Comment: @vonbrand Yes, I know.  As I said, they aren't quite "critical". :P

Comment: I call these "Possible Inflection Points". I would avoid the word "Candidate" because I do NOT want them to use the Candidates Test on them.

Comment: I use "possible inflection points" too.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I actually used to call them important points, but that inevitably got shortened to ip’s, which was quickly confused with inflection points. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculus textbook I'm currently using (Burzynski, Applied Calculus for Business, Life and Social Sciences, XYZ Textbooks) uses the term "hypercritical point". A quick web search indicates that a few other sources use it as well.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to give more information about the textbook (title, full name of author, publisher, year published).

Comment: Thanks! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The term *Hergert Numbers* is sometimes used in my specific region of the US for the values of $x$ where $f''(x) = 0$ or $f''(x)$ is undefined. This is in reference to Rodger Hergert, an Illinois community college professor who sometime in the 1990s became very frustrated with the fact that these numbers had no good name.

But it doesn't *really* matter what you call them as long as you are precise about it and distinguish them from inflection points, so I recommend the whimsical option where you name them after a current math educator -- call the points you are talking about ***Hergert points*** and the x-values ***Hergert numbers***.

If a student asks who Hergert is, you can grin and truthfully say "some guy like me who was annoyed that these didn't have a name."

If you do adopt the terminology, he'll send you a shirt, too. As of the time of this writing, the directions to get the shirt are at [hergertnumbers.org](http://www.hergertnumbers.org/) under "If you would like your own Hergert Numbers t-shirt."

Comment: Hilarious. I typically call them "potential points of inflection".